# How to make image way small without losing quality?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I have image of large size. I am trying to make it way small for  a profile picture. But I am not able to maintain the same quality of original image? What would be better option except to cropping image?

```css
.img-wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
}
h2 {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<h2>Making image small without losing quality</h2>
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1592234789031-94bf65f630ed?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bWFuJTIwc21pbGV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: For responsiveness, it's better to use the `picture` element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture, it let's you use different images for different sizes so you can optimize size and quality